# Compute the transcendence degree (transcendence degree and tensor products)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, ideals, extension-field, dimension-theory-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator{\quot}{Quot}\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$ Let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be nontrivial ideals in $\mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ and $\mathbb C[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$, respectively. Define
$$
   R_1 = \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_k] / I_1, \quad R_2 = \mathbb C[y_1,\ldots,y_m] / I_2, \\
   R_3 = \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_k,y_1,\ldots,y_m]/(I_1+I_2).
$$
If we denote by $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ the transcendence degree of $\quot(R_1)$, $\quot(R_2)$, $\quot(R_3)$ over $\mathbb C$, respectively, then $n_1+n_2 = n_3$. How to show this equality?

I tried to select transcendence bases for $\quot(R_1)$ and $\quot(R_2)$ over $\mathbb C$ and then to show that their union will be a transcendence basis for $\quot(R_3)$. But unfortunately I don't see how to show the algebraic independence and the generating property for this union of bases. Maybe my approach is incorrect and there is some other way to show the desired equality?

*P.S.* The equality in the question implies that the dimension of the product of algebraic varieties is the sum of their dimensions since the dimension can be defined as the transcendence degree of the functions field over $\mathbb C$.

*Update.* As **Georges Elencwajg** wrote in his answer and comments below, $R_3 = R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb C} R_2$ and 
$$\quot(R_3) = \quot(\quot(R_1)\otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)).$$ So it sufficient to show that for transcendental extensions $F_1$ and $F_2$ of $\mathbb C$ we have 
$$\tr\deg \quot(F_1 \otimes_{\mathbb C} F_2) = \tr\deg F_1 + \tr\deg F_2.$$
Is this equality well-known or at least does it hold in general?

Comment: Nice question, subtler than some (hum, hum, ...) realize :-). +1

Comment: Dear Nimza, the tensor product is indeed a localization **but** you are only allowed to divide by products of polynomials in the $x$'s and polynomials in the $y$'s. For example $\frac {1}{f(x)g(y)}\in \mathbb C(x) \otimes_\mathbb C \mathbb C(y)$ but $\frac {1} {x+y} \notin \mathbb C(x) \otimes_\mathbb C \mathbb C(y)$.This  point is indeed rarely discussed in textbooks.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I see, thanks. The problem is that I have to prove that the dimension of the product of varieties is the sum of dimensions using the definition of dimension based on transcendence degree, so I can't go backwards to varieties

Comment: Dear Nimza, follow the Noether theorem route or, for a more algebraic proof, look at [Milne](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jmilne.org%2Fmath%2FCourseNotes%2FAG510.pdf&ei=wmAwVMqkJIPaaub4gNAI&usg=AFQjCNFQqmGyjXPqTJUbLEicTLNjHU8LYA&sig2=oZaS2nZnImzvURkTsw0MKg) , Prop. 4.31, page 73.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\quot}{Quot}\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$Since you mention $\quot(R_i)$, the $R_i$'s must be domains or equivalently the $I_i$'s must be prime, which I now assume.  The keys to your  question are then:
a) The transcendence degree of $K_i=\quot(R_i)$ over $\mathbb C$ is precisely the dimension of the variety $V_i=\text {Spec}(R_i)$ defined by $R_i$.
b) The $\mathbb C$-algebra $R_3$ is the tensor product $R_3=R_1\otimes_\mathbb CR_2$, so that $V_3=V_1\times V_2$.

The required equality $n_3=n_1+n_2$ is then just the translation of the equality
c) $\operatorname {dim}V_3=\operatorname {dim}V_1+ \operatorname {dim}V_2$.

The equality c) is immediate from [Noether's normalization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma), an incredibly useful result in algebraic geometry, which is also the main ingredient for the proof of a) .

Comment: If I correctly understand you (the last sentence), first we use that $\quot(R_1 \otimes_{\mathbb C} R_2) = \quot(R_1) \otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)$ and then the additivity of transcedence degree in tensor product. But the proof of the additivity is a bit unclear for me, can I find it in some book/notes?

Comment: Dear Nimza, actually we have $\quot(R_3) =\quot[ \quot( R_1) \otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)]$ because $\quot( R_1) \otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)$ is **not** a field  . 
I have  deleted this part of the answer because it would be a bit long to rectify. I am sorry for having misled you and maybe other readers by implicitly claiming that $\quot( R_1) \otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)$ **is** a field.

Comment: Here  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(algebra)#Properties it is written that localization of modules respects tensor products. So in the sense of $\mathbb C$-modules we have an isomorphism $\quot(R_3) = \quot(R_1) \otimes_{\mathbb C} \quot(R_2)$. But why can't we transport multiplication from the left side to the right side to get an isomorphism of fields?

Comment: Dear Nimza,I gave a short explanation in a comment to your question. If you are not convinced you might ask  a fresh question.